# How to turn off a .cfg file?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I use Trilluxe's CHScript.cfg file to find the "perfect" crosshair, which uses the number keys, and I am really tired of having a changing crosshair ingame. Is there any way I could turn off the script without altering my game files?

Comment: Uhm, delete the script? I  mean, how did you install it? Just reverse the process..

Comment: I don't want to do that b/c I use the binds to change my crosshair color depending on the background, so I can see it better.

Comment: Are you writing "exec CHScript.cfg" in the console every time you start the game or do you have it saved as "autoexec.cfg"?

Comment: I only did that once to config my crosshair. I never had to type in "exec CHScript.cfg" again since. same goes for the sparkelz bind I downloaded for turning on the hints to perform a ninja defuse in smoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining the cfg file, I found that what you need to do is make a text file on your desktop (or anywhere) and open it with a text edit program.  Then type:

```
unbind rightarrow
unbind leftarrow
unbind uparrow
unbind downarrow
unbind PGUP
unbind PGDN
unbind INS
unbind DEL
unbind HOME
unbind END

unbind KP_RIGHTARROW
unbind KP_HOME
unbind KP_UPARROW
unbind KP_PGUP
unbind KP_INS
unbind KP_END
unbind KP_DOWNARROW
unbind KP_PGDN
unbind KP_LEFTARROW
unbind KP_5
```

Then make sure you can [see file extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7). Now rename the file from `New Text Document.txt` to `endchscript.cfg`.  Open Windows Explorer and go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg` or if you changed steam directory go to `[Steam directory]\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg` then move `endchscript.cfg` to that folder.

Now start up csgo and open the console with <kbd>~</kbd> and type `exec endchscript`.  This script will stop CHscript.cfg from using all the keys it uses.

If you wish to change your crosshair again type `exec chscript` in the console, change it, then type `exec endchscript` in the console again.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go into console and type `exec config_default` and it should work, it worked for me.

Comment: seems a bit overkill to me.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to keyboard settings and click restore defaults